# PySpark on Dataproc stops with SocketTimeoutException

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

We are currently trying to run a Spark job on a Dataproc cluster using PySpark 2.2.0 except the Spark job stops after a seemingly random amount of time passes with the following error message:

```
17/07/25 00:52:48 ERROR org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:702)
```

The error could sometimes take only a couple minutes to happen or it could take 3 hours. From personal experience, the Spark job runs for about 30 minutes to 1 hour before hitting the error.

Once the Spark job hits the error, it just stops. No matter how long I wait, it outputs nothing. On YARN ResourceManager, the application status is still labeled as "RUNNING" and I must Ctrl+C to terminate the program. At that point, the application is labelled as "FINISHED".

I run the Spark job using `/path/to/spark/bin/spark-submit --jars /path/to/jar/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar spark_job.py` command on the master node's console. The JAR file is necessary because the Spark job streams messages from Kafka (running on the same cluster as the Spark job) and pushes some messages back to the same Kafka to a different topic.

I've already looked at some other answers on this site (primarily [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168693/google-dataproc-timing-out-and-killing-excutors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412713/spark-streaming-data-pipelines-on-dataproc-experiencing-sudden-frequent-socket-t)) and they have been somewhat helpful but we haven't been able to track down where in the log might it state what caused the executors to die. So far, I've monitored the nodes during the task through the YARN ResourceManager as well as gone through the logs located in `/var/logs/hadoop-yarn` directory in every node. The  only "clue" I could find in the log was `org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM` which is the only line that is written to the dead executor's logs.

As a last ditch effort, we attempted to increase the cluster's memory size in the hopes that the issue will just go away but it hasn't. Originally, the cluster was running on a 1 master 2 workers cluster with 4vCPU, 15GB memory. We created a new Dataproc cluster, this time with 1 master and 3 workers, with the workers each having 8vCPU 52GB memory (master has same specs as previous).

What we would like to know is:
1. Where/how can I see the exception that is causing the executors to be terminated?
2. Is this an issue with how Spark is configured?
3. Dataproc image version is "preview". Could that possibly be the cause of the error?
and ultimately,
4. How do we resolve this issue? What other steps can we take?

This Spark job needs to continuously stream from Kafka for an indefinite amount of time so we would like this error to be fixed rather than prolonging the time it takes for the error to occur.

Here are some screenshots from the YARN ResourceManager to demonstrate what we are seeing:

Cluster Metrics
[image: Cluster Metrics]

Executor Summary
[image]

The screenshots are from before the Spark job stopped from the error.

And this is the Spark configuration file located in `/path/to/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` (did not change anything from the default setting by Dataproc):

```
spark.master yarn
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.yarn.jars=local:/usr/lib/spark/jars/*
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://highmem-m/user/spark/eventlog

# Dynamic allocation on YARN
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 1
spark.executor.instances 10000
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 10000
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio 0.0

spark.yarn.historyServer.address highmem-m:18080
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs://highmem-m/user/spark/eventlog

spark.executor.cores 2
spark.executor.memory 4655m
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 465

# Overkill
spark.yarn.am.memory 4655m
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead 465

spark.driver.memory 3768m
spark.driver.maxResultSize 1884m
spark.rpc.message.maxSize 512

# Add ALPN for Bigtable
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions 
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions 

# Disable Parquet metadata caching as its URI re-encoding logic does
# not work for GCS URIs (b/28306549). The net effect of this is that
# Parquet metadata will be read both driver side and executor side.
spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false

# User-supplied properties.
#Mon Jul 24 23:12:12 UTC 2017
spark.executor.cores=4
spark.executor.memory=18619m
spark.driver.memory=3840m
spark.driver.maxResultSize=1920m
spark.yarn.am.memory=640m
spark.executorEnv.PYTHONHASHSEED=0
```

I'm not quite sure where the `User-supplied properties` came from.

**Edit:**
Some additional information about the clusters:
I use the zookeeper, kafka, and jupyter initialization action scripts found at `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions` in the order of zookeeper -> kafka -> jupyter (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links at the moment)

**Edit 2:**
From @Dennis's insightful questions, we ran the Spark job while paying particular attention to the executors that have higher On Heap Storage Memory used. What I noticed is that it is always the executors from worker #0 that have significantly higher storage memory usage compared to the other executors. The stdout file for the executors of worker #0 are always empty. These three lines are repeated many times over in stderr:

```
17/07/27 16:32:01 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:01 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:01 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:04 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:04 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:04 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:07 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:07 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:07 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:09 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:09 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:09 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:10 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:10 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:10 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:13 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:13 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:13 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:14 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:14 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:14 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:15 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:15 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:15 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:18 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
17/07/27 16:32:18 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to 
17/07/27 16:32:18 INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to
```

It seems to be repeating every 1~3 seconds.

As for the stdout and stderr for the other executors from other worker nodes, they are empty.

**Edit 3:**
As mentioned from @Dennis's comments, we kept the Kafka topic the Spark job was consuming from with replication factor of 1. I also found that I've forgotten to add worker #2 to zookeeper.connect in the Kafka config file and also forgot to give the consumer streaming messages from Kafka in Spark a group ID. I've fixed those places (remade topic with replication factor of 3) and observed that now the workload mainly focuses on worker #1. Following the suggestions from @Dennis, I've run `sudo jps` after SSH-ing to worker #1 and get the following output:

`[Removed this section to save character space; it was only the error messages from a failed call to jmap so it didn't hold any useful information]`

**Edit 4:**
I'm now seeing this in worker #1 executors' stdout files:

```
2017-07-27 22:16:24
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
===Truncated===
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 814592K, used 470009K [0x000000063c180000, 0x000000069e600000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 799744K, 56% used [0x000000063c180000,0x0000000657e53598,0x000000066ce80000)
  from space 14848K, 97% used [0x000000069d780000,0x000000069e5ab1b8,0x000000069e600000)
  to   space 51200K, 0% used [0x0000000698200000,0x0000000698200000,0x000000069b400000)
 ParOldGen       total 574464K, used 180616K [0x0000000334400000, 0x0000000357500000, 0x000000063c180000)
  object space 574464K, 31% used [0x0000000334400000,0x000000033f462240,0x0000000357500000)
 Metaspace       used 49078K, capacity 49874K, committed 50048K, reserved 1093632K
  class space    used 6054K, capacity 6263K, committed 6272K, reserved 1048576K
```

and

```
2017-07-27 22:06:44
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
===Truncated===
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 608768K, used 547401K [0x000000063c180000, 0x000000066a280000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 601088K, 89% used [0x000000063c180000,0x000000065d09c498,0x0000000660c80000)
  from space 7680K, 99% used [0x0000000669b00000,0x000000066a2762c8,0x000000066a280000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x0000000665a80000,0x0000000665a80000,0x0000000667e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 535552K, used 199304K [0x0000000334400000, 0x0000000354f00000, 0x000000063c180000)
  object space 535552K, 37% used [0x0000000334400000,0x00000003406a2340,0x0000000354f00000)
 Metaspace       used 48810K, capacity 49554K, committed 49792K, reserved 1093632K
  class space    used 6054K, capacity 6263K, committed 6272K, reserved 1048576K
```

When the error happened, an executor from worker #2 received `SIGNAL TERM` and was labeled as dead. At this time, it was the only dead executor.

Strangely, the Spark job picked back up again after 10 minutes or so. Looking at the Spark UI interface, only executors from worker #1 are active and the rest are dead. First time this has happened.

**Edit 5:**
Again, following @Dennis's suggestions (thank you, @Dennis!), this time ran `sudo -u yarn jmap -histo <pid>`. This is the top 10 of the most memory hogging classes from `CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend` after about 10 minutes:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:        244824      358007944  [B
   2:        194242      221184584  [I
   3:       2062554      163729952  [C
   4:        746240       35435976  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   5:           738       24194592  [Lorg.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.MemoryBlock;
   6:        975513       23412312  java.lang.String
   7:        129645       13483080  java.io.ObjectStreamClass
   8:        451343       10832232  java.lang.StringBuilder
   9:         38880       10572504  [Z
  10:        120807        8698104  java.lang.reflect.Field
```

Also, I've encountered a new type of error which caused an executor to die. It produced some failed tasks highlighted in the Spark UI and found this in the executor's stderr:

```
17/07/28 00:44:03 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6821.0 (TID 2585)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.checkInvariants(BlockInfoManager.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.readerCount_$eq(BlockInfoManager.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/07/28 00:44:03 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.1 in stage 6821.0 (TID 2586)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.checkInvariants(BlockInfoManager.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfo.readerCount_$eq(BlockInfoManager.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$releaseAllLocksForTask$2.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/07/28 00:44:03 ERROR org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for /opt/conda/bin/python
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Block rdd_5480_0 is not locked for reading
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.unlock(BlockInfoManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseLock(BlockManager.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(BlockManager.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator$$anon$1.completion(CompletionIterator.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
17/07/28 00:44:03 ERROR org.apache.spark.util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[stdout writer for /opt/conda/bin/python,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Block rdd_5480_0 is not locked for reading
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.unlock(BlockInfoManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseLock(BlockManager.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(BlockManager.scala:516)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator$$anon$1.completion(CompletionIterator.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
```

**Edit 6:**
This time, I took the `jmap` after 40 minutes of running:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         23667      391136256  [B
   2:         25937       15932728  [I
   3:        159174       12750016  [C
   4:           334       10949856  [Lorg.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.MemoryBlock;
   5:         78437        5473992  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   6:        125322        3007728  java.lang.String
   7:         40931        2947032  java.lang.reflect.Field
   8:         63431        2029792  com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Registration
   9:         20897        1337408  com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.UnsafeCacheFields$UnsafeObjectField
  10:         20323         975504  java.util.HashMap
```

These are the results of `ps ux`:

```
  USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
yarn       601  0.8  0.9 3008024 528812 ?      Sl   16:12   1:17 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dproc_nodema
yarn      6086  6.3  0.0  96764 24340 ?        R    18:37   0:02 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8036  8.2  0.0  96296 24136 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8173  9.4  0.0  97108 24444 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8240  9.0  0.0  96984 24576 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8329  7.6  0.0  96948 24720 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8420  8.5  0.0  96240 23788 ?        R    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8487  6.0  0.0  96864 24308 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8554  0.0  0.0  96292 23724 ?        S    18:37   0:00 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
yarn      8564  0.0  0.0  19100  2448 pts/0    R+   18:37   0:00 ps ux
yarn     31705  0.0  0.0  13260  2756 ?        S    17:56   0:00 bash /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/<user_name>/app
yarn     31707  0.0  0.0  13272  2876 ?        Ss   17:56   0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
yarn     31713  0.4  0.7 2419520 399072 ?      Sl   17:56   0:11 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx6
yarn     31771  0.0  0.0  13260  2740 ?        S    17:56   0:00 bash /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/<user_name>/app
yarn     31774  0.0  0.0  13284  2800 ?        Ss   17:56   0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
yarn     31780 11.1  1.4 21759016 752132 ?     Sl   17:56   4:31 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -server -Xmx1
yarn     31883  0.1  0.0  96292 27308 ?        S    17:56   0:02 /opt/conda/bin/python -m pyspark.daemon
```

The `pid` of the `CoarseGrainedExecutorBackEnd` is `31780` in this case.

**Edit 7:**
Increasing `heartbeatInterval` in the Spark settings did not change anything, which makes sense in hindsight.

I created a short bash script that reads from Kafka with the console consumer for 5 seconds and writes the messages into a text file. The text file is uploaded to Hadoop where Spark streams from. We tested whether the Timeout was related to Kafka through this method.

- Streaming from Hadoop and outputting to Kafka from Spark caused SocketTimeout
- Streaming from Kafka directly and not outputting to Kafka from Spark caused SocketTimeout
- Streaming from Hadoop and not outputting to Kafka from Spark caused SocketTimeout

So we moved on with the assumption that Kafka had nothing to do with the Timeout.

We installed Stackdriver Monitoring to see memory usage as the Timeout occurred. Nothing really interesting from the metrics; memory usage looked relatively stable throughout (hovering around 10~15% at most for the busiest nodes).

We guessed perhaps something to do with the communication between the worker nodes is what could be causing the issue. Right now, our amount of data traffic is very low so even one worker can handle all the workload with relative ease.

Running the Spark job on a single node cluster while streaming from Kafka brokers from a different cluster seemed to have stopped the SocketTimeout... except the `AssertionError` documented above now frequently occurs.

Per @Dennis's suggestion, I created a new cluster (also single node) without the jupyter initialization script this time which means Spark runs on Python v2.7.9 now (without Anaconda). The first run, Spark encountered `SocketTimeoutException` in just 15 seconds. The second time ran for just over 2 hours, failing with the same `AssertionError`. I'm starting to wonder if this is a problem with Spark's internals. The third run ran for about 40 minutes and then ran into `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Did using higher-memory workers increase the time it took before the error happens each time?

Comment: @DennisHuo As far as I can tell, increasing memory doesn't seem like it has changed how long it takes for the error to occur

Comment: Did you look through the "stdout", "stderr" and Thread Dump links that Spark provides for any additional clues? Especially for ones that have "On Heap Storage Memory" creep up above all the others. Is the memory creep mostly linear? What's the actual amount of time before hitting the error each time?

Comment: @DennisHuo Thank you for patience. I've added some additional info regarding stdout/stderr in Edit 2. As for memory creep, yes it has been mostly linear. About actual amount of time before error, as I've mentioned, it's been very sporadic so it is hard to give a solid answer. The most recent run has taken 15 minutes 3 seconds to hit the error. The run before that took 1 hour and 41 seconds.

Comment: The fact that it's two separate executors but both on worker 0 which has the high storage implies to me that you might have some skew in your Kafka topics. What's the source of data going into Kafka? Do you have Kafka replication factor set > 1 for the topic(s) you're using? Also, if you have it running, you should be able to SSH into the worker node with higher memory usage, and if you type `sudo jps` you should see something that looks like a Spark executor (I forget exactly, maybe CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend). Either way, find the java process using memory, then `sudo jmap -histo <pid>`

Comment: That'll tell you where all your memory is going. If you're able to share the top memory usage class names in the SO question here then you'll likely have more luck from folks recognizing known sources of memory leaks.

Comment: @DennisHuo You are absolutely right about Kafka. The topic Spark is consuming from is has only one partition and I've kept it that way for now. As mentioned in the new edits (Edit 3), I've changed the replication factor to 3. We are still on the fence about if Kafka is completely the culprit since we're not sure how a fault in Kafka could lead to the SocketTimeout in Spark.

Comment: Re: SocketTimeout, it sounded like it wasn't a timeout issue per se, but rather a worker OOMing, which can manifest as all sorts of socket errors on the other side. One thing I forgot about running jmap is that you need to run it as the userthat owns the process, in this case YARN. So you might need: `sudo -u yarn jmap -histo <pid>`

Comment: My belief with the Kafka partitioning is simply that it might be part of the cause for skew in having only one worker node do the work while the others are idle; this might not be the root cause, just that with more balanced load, at least the different workers would help share the memory burden. Either way you'll still need to get to the root cause of the memory leak though.

Comment: @DennisHuo I agree with you regarding the partitioning of Kafka; it is definitely something we must revisit on our end after we get to the bottom of this. Thank you very much for guiding me through this troubleshooting, it has been a lot of help. I've posted the results from `jmap` in Edit 5 which I hope means something (the first few class names look strange to me) and I've run into a new kind of exception which I've documented in the same edit as well. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem like a huge amount of memory yet; maybe over time it'll be interesting to see whether it's the same top 10 classes growing. I wonder how much memory is being eaten up by the Python side; if you run `sudo -u yarn ps ux` on that worker you should see processes owned by YARN; some of them will be the java processes, but I believe you'll see python subprocesses too. Also, you can take some looks at `sudo -u jstack <pid>` of the CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend the same way you use jmap to see what Java is doing at the time. There's a lot, but you can look for interesting stacks.

Comment: Your new errors also bring up the point that the Jupyter init action also switches Python over to the Conda distribution; this definitely introduces more combinations that haven't really been tested together. Have you tried running on a cluster that doesn't use the Jupyter init action to see if there's any difference? Your "block not locked for reading" error looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18406 but if you're using preview you should have Spark 2.2.0 already so that's strange.

Comment: @DennisHuo I've run the Spark job longer and took the jmap/jstash information and included in the post. I intend to run it for longer and take down the information again at that time. Is there anything I should be looking for in the output of `jstash`? It looks like a regular thread dump I can see in the Spark UI at first glance. Also, I've noticed that the AssertionError is happening more frequently now; at the time I took the jmap/jstash info, one executor has been dead due to the AssertionError and the previous run at the job has failed due to the same error.

Comment: @DennisHuo I would say that the AssertionError has started happening at around the same time I changed the Kafka topics to have replication factor of 3. It's hard to say if they are correlated especially since the Kafka/Zookeeper logs in every node don't have any records of an error occurring.

Comment: @DennisHuo And to answer your questions about Python versions: I created a new cluster without running the Jupyter init-action script and while I didn't get any AssertionError, I did get the same SocketTimeoutException in about 10 minutes (with Kafka topic at replication factor of 3). I used the default Dataproc Python version of 2.7.9

Comment: @DennisHuo I'm sorry, it should be `jstack`, not `jstash`.

Comment: re: Stack traces, it'd be good to know what the worker is mostly doing that might lead to timeouts. It'd also help provide insight into the workload, e.g. is it doing lots of shuffling, is it doing groupByKeys, is it blocking on local-disk spill, is it blocking on GCS access, is it doing lots of API calls to some other non-GCP service, etc.

Comment: @DennisHuo What you're saying makes sense except I can't really make sense of the thread dump... I ran `jstack` a couple of times and each time, I see that `shuffle-client` and `shuffle-server` is holding on to some locks. That could just be a coincidence and those locks may not matter. I've recently realized there was a `collect()` in the script which I took out and the `AssertionError` seems to have went away. We are currently testing it again with increased `heartbeatInterval` along with the code optimization and will report back with any new information.

Comment: @DennisHuo , I've updated with more details so please take a look whenever you have time. We've run some more tests on our own and hope it could provide some insight and would love to hear your thoughts

Comment: Are you using [preemptible VMs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/preemptible-vms) for workers? If so, the master could be getting preempted (an issue currently being fixed). Try using normal workers if this is the case.

Comment: @Jordan Unfortunately (fortunately?), we're not using any preemptible VMs for neither the workers nor the master but thank you for your input. We're still tracking down the issue and hope to post an answer once we find a solution.

Comment: @user8366430 Were you able to investigate any further into your job to pinpoint the reason why your specific workload is seeing this issue?

Comment: @Jordan We only have a rough idea what is PROBABLY going wrong and if we are correct, it is most likely a coding issue within the PySpark script. However, we haven't been able to come up with a solution and unfortunately decided to put this problem on the back burner for now (we do have something else in place now that will just restart the script in case it gets stopped by reason mentioned in post as a band-aid in the mean time).

Answer (score 2):

A client of mine was seeing various production Pyspark jobs (Spark version 2.2.1) fail in Google Cloud Dataproc intermittently with a very similar stack trace to yours:

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:711)
```

I found that disabling ipv6 on the Dataproc cluster VMs seemed to fix the issue. One way to do that is adding these lines to a Dataproc init script so they are run at cluster creation time:

```
printf "\nnet.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1\nnet.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1\n" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately we don't have the means to test this right now but if someone else can verify that disabling IPv6 works, I'd be happy to accept this answer